# I changed hostname, now tfs does not show pending changes or mappings

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I changed my computer's host name yesterday and now in TFS I do not see the mapped folders in the source control explorer, nor do I see my pending changes.

Is there a way to get these back? I have pending changes but cannot be sure of every file with changes so I cannot do a fresh get as I may lose changes.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the workspace computer name.

Open Developer Command Prompt or Run cmd

```
cd c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE
```

Run this command:

```
tf workspaces /updateComputerName:MyOldComputerName /s:"http://MyServer:8080/tfs/MyCollection"
```

**UPDATE:**

If that not work, please try to clean the caches in your client machine,then remap to a new folder to check that again.

---

Besides, you can also install [Team Foundation Sidekicks](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/) which providing Graphic User Interface for the administration and it's free.

1. Open the Workspace Sidekick, click Search, and select your workspace
   from the list.
2. Click the blue computer icon to Update Workspace Computer Name.

[image]

Comment: @andrewb Have you resolved your issue by above solution? any update?

Comment: No, I ran the command and I still do not see my pending changes or that I have a folder mapped

Comment: @andrewb Please try to clean the caches in your client machine,then remap to a new folder to check that again.